# How to implement Observer pattern in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, observable, mvp, observer-pattern, rest

How to implement Observer pattern using asp.net. I want to use this pattern for consuming api and send a response to the view, what will be the better way to implement it.

Comment: Web applications are stateless. What do you mean by observer in this context? client polling server or server pushing info to the client?

Comment: The Observer pattern is diametrically at odds with Rest. However, there are a few non-rest technologies under ASP.Net that implements the Observable (and not the Sub/Pub) pattern. See SignalR Real-Time and gRPC Streams.

Comment: The client is the desktop application and it's pulling data from the server through API.